# Geometry question - Prove perpendicular

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an isosceles triangle at $A$, the height $AD$, $E$ is the midpoint of $AD$, $DM \perp BE$ at $M$. Prove that $AM \perp CM$[image]

My try is Pythagorean theorem show $AC^2=AM^2+MC^2$ but this is very long and easy to confuse beacause I need new method

Comment: The data is very confusing: what does "isosceles at A" mean? That at A we have the vertex where the equal sides meet? **What is M**? A diagram will help.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I interpreted "isosceles at $A$" like you. That would be a very natural formulation in French maths.

Comment: isosceles at A mean the triangle  have $AB=AC$

Comment: @HongphucNguyen Great...and what about the other, more important and misterious, question? Why don't you attach a diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this solution uses a completely different approach, I start a new answer.

Since $\triangle BMD \sim \triangle DME$,

$$\frac{BM}{BD}=\frac{DM}{DE}$$

But $BC=2BD$ and $DA=2DE$. So, we have

$$\frac{BM}{BC}=\frac{DM}{DA}$$

Note that $\angle MBC=90^\circ-\angle BDM=\angle MDA$. Therefore, we have $\triangle MBC\sim\triangle MDA$.

This implies that $\angle BCM=\angle DAM$.

$A$, $M$, $D$ and $C$ are concyclic.

So, we have $\angle AMC=\angle ADC=90^\circ$

Comment: why $\frac{BM}{BD}=\frac{DM}{DE}$

Comment: They are the corresponding sides of similar triangles. $\triangle BMD\sim\triangle DME$

Comment: my idea is why $\triangle BMD\sim\triangle DME$

Comment: (1) $\angle BMD=\angle DME=90^\circ$ (2) $\angle DBM=90^\circ-\angle BDM=\angleEDM$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\overrightarrow{DB}=x$ and $\overrightarrow{DE}=y$. Then $x\cdot y=0$.

$\overrightarrow{DM}=(1-t)x+ty$ for some $t\in(0,1)$. Since $DM\perp BE$,

\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{DM}\cdot (x-y)&=0\\
[(1-t)x+ty]\cdot x&=[(1-t)x+ty]\cdot y\\
(1-t)x\cdot x&=t y\cdot y
\end{align}

We have $\overrightarrow{AM}=\overrightarrow{DM}-\overrightarrow{DA}=(1-t)x+(t-2)y$ and $\overrightarrow{CM}=\overrightarrow{DM}-\overrightarrow{DC}=(2-t)x+ty$.

\begin{align}
&\;\overrightarrow{AM}\cdot \overrightarrow{CM}\\
=&\;[(1-t)x+(t-2)y]\cdot[(2-t)x+ty]\\
=&\;(1-t)(2-t)x\cdot x+(t-2)ty\cdot y\\
=&\;(1-t)(2-t)x\cdot x+(t-2)(1-t)x\cdot x\\
=&\;0
\end{align}

So $AM\perp CM$.

Comment: i don't know about vector, you can given new method

Comment: @HongphucNguyen Just found a new method. Please see my other answer to the post.